# Magento 2 REST API - Update Payment Method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, rest-api

Is it possible to update payment method in Sales Order using Magento 2 API when Order is already created with a different payment method?
If it is, Can someone point to how this could be done?
Should something else be updated beside Order using REST API so a different payment method is selected when you open/check the order from the backend?

What I was trying is using different data for "POST /V1/orders/" to change a payment method. So, I was trying to change from "VISA" to "MASTERCARD". 
Payment servise used is MPAY24.
Payment method codes are: mpay24cw_visa and mpay24cw_mastercard.

Thanks.

### UPDATE:

I am trying to build an external approach to Magento API from a different CMS so I could create an order but in some cases when I create an order and then customer selects e.g. VISA credit cart but something is wrong with it and payment system returns an error the customer will try a different payment method. In that case I'm not sure If I can update payment method of already created order in Magento. Can I?